# Redirect с предыдущим url

Tags: java

Проблема в следующем - хочу сделать многоязычное Java web приложение. Задача чтобы во всех страницах приложения была возможность переключаться между языками. Сделал `header.jsp` со сменой языка и подключаю его через `include` в других jsp страницах.

Как мне после смены языка возвращаться на ту страницу откуда пользователь вызвал смену языка?

Например, пользователь залогинился, передача параметров через `POST`, а потом сразу нажал смену языка.

`request.getHeader("Referer")` - работает, но только с `GET`, а мне необходимо чтобы и с `POST` (когда параметры в теле запроса). Помогите пожалуйста, натолкните на мысль.

Comment: Сохрани текущий url в сессии, и при смене языка делай редирект обратно на этот урл

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как достать url?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите мой [гитхаб](https://github.com/o-morenets/Hospital).
Я делал через фильтр локали:
[JSP, отвечеющий за языки](https://github.com/o-morenets/Hospital/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/view/i18n/languages.jsp),
[Собственно, сам фильтр](https://github.com/o-morenets/Hospital/blob/master/src/main/java/controller/filters/LocaleFilter.java),
[Набор доступных локалей](https://github.com/o-morenets/Hospital/blob/master/src/main/java/i18n/SupportedLocale.java).
Ну и, естественно, нужно плодключить Resource Bundle, в котором все слова предоставить на всех поддерживаемых языках.